# What is the purpose of the elements of this antenna?

Tags: antenna, wifi, pcb-antenna, antenna-array

I have a 5GHz 23dBi Wi-Fi panel antenna which has the geometry shown in the images below.

[image: 23dBi panel antenna][image]

I have been quite curious as to the purpose of this bizarre antenna design. The elements have such unique shapes, and each is slightly different, though there is plenty of symmetry. Some elements are not connected to anything (parasitics?) but many are tied to the centerline. The antenna has a ground plane below (about an inch) and the driven elements are etched on a PCB.

How does a design such as this come about, with such complicated geometry? I am familiar with electromagnetics and antenna theory to some extent, but I do not understand this yet.

Comment: A prime example of electronics black magic.

Comment: @Arsenal, or maybe a result of optimization work of an expensive 3-D field solver?

Comment: Or more proof of alien visitation....

Comment: I think there is a message encoded...

Comment: Does the antenna perform the gain as advertised?

Comment: it's a phase array, so there's about \$ 1 \lambda \$ delay between adjacent elements, but how that design was reached I cannot say.

Comment: It may be a close relative of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_antenna

Comment: This is a single antenna array.  It could be worse: some radar systems from the end of the last century had separate delay electronics for each element so that the antenna could simultaneously track several targets.   Count your blessings!  There is a lot going on in there with simultaneous phasing and impedance matching over a broad band.  Way above my paygrade.

Comment: Alien crop circles on the fields are actually microstrip antennas

Comment: did you also notice that the elements except for the parasitic are all grounded (they ground where the bolts hold the pcb), and on other panel designs the elements do not connect to ground at all

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to be a patch antenna array, analogous (among many images you could find googling around) to this one:

[image]

Patch antenna arrays are a special kind of [*microstrip antennas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstrip_antenna). You can find many details about them in [this article](http://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/3144-a-practical-guide-to-the-designof-microstrip-antenna-arrays).

A relevant excerpt:

> PLANAR MICROSTRIP ARRAYS
>
> Planar microstrip arrays are used to form a pencil beam and array elements can be fed in a variety of ways. In the first example the corporate feed is used to activate every array element separately. An example is shown in Figure10,4 which consists of patch radiators and a network of microstrip feed lines. The patch feeds are inset to achieve a good match to the feed lines. The feed lines are made of similar length so the beam pointing is broadside to the array at all frequencies. The bandwidth is limited by the patches themselves, which is typically a few percent. Feed lines are rather long, adding to loss mechanisms, and spurious radiation is caused at bends and junctions.
>
> [image]

Since you said you are somewhat knowledgeable of antenna theory, you might appreciate how such a planar antenna array may generate a useful radiation pattern, as shown by this image of a simulation:

[image]

**EDIT** (After a more thorough search on the Internet)

You may find the following article very interesting, since it is a concise and clear explanation of the basics on patch antennas:

- [**The Basics of Patch Antennas, Updated;** *By D. Orban and G.J.K. Moernaut; Orban Microwave Products*](http://orbanmicrowave.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Orban-Patch-Antennas-2009-rev.pdf)

Some excerpts:

> Topics include principles of operation, impedance matching, radiation patterns, circular polarization, bandwidth, efficiency, alternative feed types, stacked patches and higher mode behavior.

[...]

> ### Properties Of A Basic Microstrip Patch
>
> A microstrip or patch antenna is a low-profile antenna that has a
>   number of advantages over other antennas:  it is lightweight,
>   inexpensive, and electronics like LNA’s and SSPA’s can be integrated
>   with these  antennas quite easily. While the antenna can be a 3- D
>   structure (wrapped around a cylinder, for  example), it is usually
>   flat and that is why patch antennas are sometimes referred to as
>   planar antennas.